# css left causes elements to show as inline

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I am creating a "More" button for a navigation bar.
The code takes several existing buttons and appends them to an undisplayed div element, which becomes visible when the mouse hovers over the button.
The button is the last in the row. The div slides out of the screen, so I inserted a `right:0px;`/`left:0px` (depending on the language direction) rule to the css. But the moment that happened, all the `li` elements (the buttons which were added to the div) are appearing inline next to each other, instead of one below the other.

The HTML structure is:

```
<div id="toolbarcontrol">
<nav>
<ul id="menuList">
<li>Button</li>
<li>Button</li>
<li>Button</li>
//this is where the code inserts the new button.
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

The jquery code is:

```
   function MoreButton() { //Specific Buttons appending
        window.jQuery && (clearInterval(myMoreButtonInterval), jQuery(window.parent.document).ready(function() {
            //Getting buttons to append.
        var buttons = $('#MoreButton').attr("data-buttons").split(",");
            //Getting necessary CSS.
        var styleText = $('style').html();
        var backgroundcolor = $('#toolbarControl').css("background-color"); //Getting the background color from the menu bar.
            //Changing CSS based on language.
            if (document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("dir") == "RTL") {
                styleText += '\n' + '#toolbarmorebutton .nav-item {display:inherit;}' + '\n' + '#itemMore:hover > #toolbarmorebutton{display:block !important; background-color:' + backgroundcolor + ' !important;}' + '\n' + '#toolbarmorebutton {position:fixed; left:0px;}';
            } else {
                styleText += '\n' + '#toolbarmorebutton .nav-item {display:inherit;}' + '\n' + '#itemMore:hover > #toolbarmorebutton{display:block !important; background-color:' + backgroundcolor + ' !important;}' + '\n' + '#toolbarmorebutton {position:fixed; right:0px;}';
            }
            //Applying CSS.
        $('style').html(styleText); //Applying style.
            //Adding new button and div (language based).
            var moretext;
        //Code that selects the language goes here, it works ok but is long so I cut it out.
        $("#menuList").append('<li id="itemMore" role="menuitem" class="nav-item" tabindex="-1"><p title="More options" class="link color-s1" id="lnkMore" tabindex="-1">' + moretext + '</p><div id="toolbarmorebutton" style="display: none;" title="More options"></div></li>');
            //Adding buttons if they were chosen.
        if (buttons.includes('Sign in')) {
        $('#itemSignIn').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
        }
        if (buttons.includes('Folder')) {
        $('#itemFolder').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
        }
        if (buttons.includes('Preferences')) {
        $('#itemPrefs').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
        }
        if (buttons.includes('Language')) {
        $('#itemLanguages').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
        }
        if (buttons.includes('Help')) {
        $('#itemHelp').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
        }
    }))};

    try {
        var myMoreButtonInterval = setInterval("MoreButton()", 500)
    } catch (n) {
        console.log(n)
    }
```

How can I keep the buttons one after the other, but have the div not disappear off the screen?
[image]
[image]

Comment: If your question is about CSS than why do you only add JS and HTML but no CSS? Or isn't the problem related to CSS?

Comment: @SuperDJ the css is added in the jquery code for reasons I won't get in to. See the section with the styleText variable.

Comment: @NimrodYanai Please add the other relevant css (ul/li/nav/html/body .. ) The css related to the toolbar button is not adequate to recreate the issue. At a guess, you probably need to change your display attribute to block or inline block but other html may be affected.